# Detect motion in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, motion-detection

I need help to detect motion in JavaFX. Start recording only when motion is detected and stop when there is no detected motion for sometime.
Everything is working fine but motion detection part is not working good.

I used the sarxos library: https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture

**Any suggestion?**

this is javafx controller class.

```
public class MonitorController implements Initializable {

    private static double v;
    @FXML
    private VBox monitor;
    @FXML
    JFXButton btnStartCamera, btnStopCamera;
    @FXML
    JFXComboBox<WebCamInfo> cbCameraOptions;
    @FXML
    BorderPane bpWebCamPaneHolder;
    @FXML
    FlowPane fpBottomPane;
    @FXML
    ImageView imgWebCamCapturedImage;
    int i = 0;
    @FXML
    private JFXSlider jfxSlider;
    private BufferedImage grabbedImage, grabbedImage2;
    private boolean stopCamera = false, stopCamera2 = false;
    private Webcam selWebCam = null;
    private ObjectProperty<Image> imageProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<Image>();
    private IMediaWriter writer, writer2;
    private String cameraListPromptText = "Choose Camera";
    private File file = null, file2 = null;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh-mm-ss aa");

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        fpBottomPane.setDisable(true);
        ObservableList<WebCamInfo> options = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        int webCamCounter = 0;
        for (Webcam webcam : Webcam.getWebcams()) {
            WebCamInfo webCamInfo = new WebCamInfo();
            webCamInfo.setWebCamIndex(webCamCounter);
            webCamInfo.setWebCamName(webcam.getName());
            options.add(webCamInfo);
            webCamCounter++;
        }
        cbCameraOptions.setItems(options);
        cbCameraOptions.setPromptText(cameraListPromptText);
        cbCameraOptions.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((arg01, arg11, arg2) -> {
            if (arg2 != null) {
                System.out.println("WebCam Index: " + arg2.getWebCamIndex() + ": WebCam Name:" + arg2.getWebCamName());
                initializeWebCam(arg2.getWebCamIndex());
            }
        });
    }

    protected void setImageViewSize() {

        double height = bpWebCamPaneHolder.getHeight();
        double width = bpWebCamPaneHolder.getWidth();
        imgWebCamCapturedImage.setFitHeight(height);
        imgWebCamCapturedImage.setFitWidth(width);
        imgWebCamCapturedImage.setSmooth(true);
        imgWebCamCapturedImage.setPreserveRatio(false);
    }

    private void initializeWebCam(final int webCamIndex) {

        Task<Void> webCamIntilizer = new Task<Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                if (selWebCam == null) {
                    selWebCam = Webcam.getWebcams().get(webCamIndex);
                    selWebCam.open();
                } else {
                    closeCamera();
                    selWebCam = Webcam.getWebcams().get(webCamIndex);
                    selWebCam.open();
                }
                startWebCamStream();
                return null;
            }

        };

        new Thread(webCamIntilizer).start();
        fpBottomPane.setDisable(false);
        btnStartCamera.setDisable(true);
    }

    //main method that will record the videos
    private synchronized void startWebCamStream() {
        stopCamera = false;
        stopCamera2 = false;
        Date date = new Date();
        File folder = new File("VideoRecordings");

        //without motion detection video
        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                file = new File(folder,"NormalVideo("+dateFormat.format(date.getTime())+").mp4");
                writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(file.getName());
                Dimension size = WebcamResolution.QVGA.getSize();
                writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_H264, size.width, size.height);
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                try {
                    while (!stopCamera) {
                        if ((grabbedImage = selWebCam.getImage()) != null) {
                            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                                final Image mainiamge = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(grabbedImage, null);
                                imageProperty.set(mainiamge);
                            });
                            BufferedImage image = ConverterFactory.convertToType(grabbedImage, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
                            IConverter converter = ConverterFactory.createConverter(image, IPixelFormat.Type.YUV420P);
                            IVideoPicture frame = converter.toPicture(image, ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) * 1000));
                            frame.setKeyFrame(true);
                            frame.setQuality(0);
                            writer.encodeVideo(0,frame);
                        }
//                        grabbedImage.flush();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                } finally {
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        //display video and pictures
        imgWebCamCapturedImage.imageProperty().bind(imageProperty);

        //with motion detection video
        Task<Void> task1 = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                WebcamMotionDetector detector = new WebcamMotionDetector(selWebCam);
                detector.setInterval(100); 

                jfxSlider.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                    v = (double) newValue;
                    detector.setPixelThreshold((int) v);
                    });
                detector.start();

                file2 = new File(folder,"motionDetected("+dateFormat.format(date.getTime())+").mp4");
                writer2 = ToolFactory.makeWriter(file2.getName());
                Dimension size = WebcamResolution.QVGA.getSize();
                writer2.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_H264, size.width, size.height);


                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                while (!stopCamera2) {
                    if ((grabbedImage2 = selWebCam.getImage()) != null) {
                        if(detector.isMotion()){
                            while (detector.isMotion()) {
                                BufferedImage image = ConverterFactory.convertToType(grabbedImage2, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
                                IConverter converter = ConverterFactory.createConverter(image, IPixelFormat.Type.YUV420P);
                                IVideoPicture frame = converter.toPicture(image, ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) * 1000));
                                frame.setKeyFrame(true);
                                frame.setQuality(0);
                                writer2.encodeVideo(0, frame);
                            }
                            grabbedImage2.flush();
//                            writer2.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        };


        Thread th = new Thread(task);
        Thread th2 = new Thread(task1);
        th.setDaemon(true);
        th.start();
        th2.setDaemon(true);
        th2.start();

    }

    private void closeCamera() {
        if (selWebCam != null) {
            selWebCam.close();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void stopCamera(ActionEvent event) {
        stopCameraAndRecording();
        btnStopCamera.setDisable(true);
        btnStartCamera.setDisable(false);
    }

    @FXML
    private void startCamera(ActionEvent event) {
        if(selWebCam.close()){
        }else{
            startWebCamStream();
            btnStopCamera.setDisable(false);
            btnStartCamera.setDisable(true);
        }
    }

    class WebCamInfo {
        private String webCamName;
        private int webCamIndex;

        public String getWebCamName() {
            return webCamName;
        }

        public void setWebCamName(String webCamName) {
            this.webCamName = webCamName;
        }

        public int getWebCamIndex() {
            return webCamIndex;
        }

        public void setWebCamIndex(int webCamIndex) {
            this.webCamIndex = webCamIndex;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return webCamName;
        }

    }

    private void stopCameraAndRecording(){
        stopCamera = true;
        stopCamera2 = true;
        if (writer2!=null && writer2.isOpen()) {
            writer2.close();
        }
        if (writer!=null && writer.isOpen()) {
            writer.close();
        }
        closeCamera();
        Webcam.shutdown();
    }

}
```

Comment: welcome to SO! maybe you can shorten your code sample to some "critical" section - most likely people here are not willing to read through all of this. At least skip import statements to make it shorter...

Comment: ok i have short that code